# Devise: Ability to pass parameters to the registrations#sign_up action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Once in a while we send customized registration links to our leads. The link contains parameters than can be used to pre-fill the registration form.

```
http://www.example.com/users/sign_up?user[company_name]=Foo&user[region]=NA
```

Our registration form has fields for accepting company name and region. Which can be pre-filled based on the registration link.

This should work in practice, but it doesn't due to how the `registrations#new` action is implemented. The [new](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L6) action calls the  `build_resource` method with an empty hash.

```
def new
  resource = build_resource({})
  respond_with resource
end
```

The [build_resource](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L85) method ignores the `resource_params` when the input is non nil.

```
def build_resource(hash=nil)
  hash ||= resource_params || {}
  self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash, session)
end
```

I had to over-ride the the `new` action in my registrations controller to overcome this issue. I don't like my solution as it is brittle.

```
def new
  resource = build_resource
  respond_with resource
end
```

Is there a reason why the `new` action is invoked with an empty hash? Can it be invoked with out empty hash(like in the `create` action)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up overriding `build_resource` and scoping the change to `new` action.

```
def build_resource(hash=nil)
  # scope the change to new actions 
  return super unless action_name == "new"
  super.tap do |user|
    user.company_name = params[:user][:company_name]
    user.reg‭ion = params[:user][:reg‭ion]      
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the intended behaviour of the `build_resource` method. Similar to `Model.new` you can either pass a hash of initializing properties or nothing, resulting in a pre-filled and an empty model respectively.

If you want to make your controller action more explicit you could instead call `build_resource(params[:user])` which should avoid the brittleness you're concerned about.

Comment: The solution is brittle because I can't call `super` on the `new` method. Replacing the method is brittle compared to wrapping a method using `super`.