# Passing params from link_to to sign up form(devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, parameters

We've created devise User model containing additional field called `type` for distinguishing between different types of users. I have a `register` route where you can choose who you want to be registered as. The page contains 2 `link_to` which redirect to the same devise user form. I want to pass type parameter to overwritten register controller, so that type will be automatically assigned.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

private

    def sign_up_params
        #assiging type
        params.require(:user).permit(:type, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

## /register

```
<%= link_to "Register as Developer", new_user_registration_path(:user => {:type => "developer")}) %>
<%= link_to "Register as Designer", new_user_registration_path(:user => {:type => "designer")}) %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143931/devise-ability-to-pass-parameters-to-the-registrationssign-up-action

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <%= link_to "Register as Developer", new_user_registration_path({:user => {:type => "developer"}}) %>
 <%= link_to "Register as Designer", new_user_registration_path({:user => {:type => "designer"}}) %>
```

Add this code:

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

   def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
     registration_params = [:type, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]

     if params[:action] == 'update'
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
       }
    elsif params[:action] == 'create'
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params) 
       }
   end
  end
 end
```

Comment: Params are successfully passed to sign up form but after user is registered i can see in console that type is set to nil. Looks like after submission this parameter is not passed further. Or maybe i need to do some extra work in my register controller?